# Get Total Input Path Count in Hadoop Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

We are trying to grab the total number of input paths our MapReduce program is iterating through in our mapper. We are going to use this along with a counter to format our value depending on the index. Is there an easy way to pull the total input path count from the mapper? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look through the source for `FileInputFormat.getSplits()` - this pulls back the configuration property for `mapred.input.dir` and then resolves this CSV to an array of Paths.

These paths can still represent folders and regex's so the next thing getSplits() does is to pass the array to a protected method `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(JobContext)`. This actually goes through the dirs / regex's listed and lists the directory / regex matching files (also invoking a `PathFilter` if configured).

So with this method being protected, you could create a simple 'dummy' extension of FileInputFormat that has a listStatus method, accepting the Mapper.Context as it's argument, and in turn wrap a call to the FileInputFormat.listStatus method:

```
public class DummyFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat {
    public List<FileStatus> listStatus(Context mapContext) throws IOException {
        return super.listStatus(mapContext);
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
            TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        // dummy input format, so this will never be called
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: In fact it looks like `FileInputFormat` already does this for you, configuring a job property `mapreduce.input.num.files` at the end of the getSplits() method (at least in 1.0.2, probably introduced in 0.20.203)

[Here's the JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1466)

Comment: Christ I got a input path not found exception when I tried this. The input path is definitely there.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace (pastebin or soemwhere like that to make formatting easier)

Comment: Chris, i'm sorry, we implemented a custom FileInputFormat that does a recursive trace. Your solution worked. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a configuration in your job with the number of input paths. just like

```
jobConf.setInt("numberOfPaths",paths.length);
```

just put the code in that place where you configure your job. After that read it out of the configuration in your `Mapper.setup(Mapper.Context context)` by getting it from the context.