# Get Total input paths in hadoop Reducer

Tags: hadoop, path

I still cannot figure out how to get the total number of input paths in hadoop. I've saw [Get Total Input Path Count in Hadoop Mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585560/get-total-input-path-count-in-hadoop-mapper), but don't understand. I just want to know that, how many files in the input path...Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said towards the end of my answer in the referenced question, if you're using v0.20.203+ of hadoop, then you can query the configuration property `mapreduce.input.num.files`

```
long inputFiles = context.getConfiguration().getLong('mapreduce.input.num.files');
```

Comment: But, why I always get 1?`int N = (int) context.getConfiguration().getLong("mapreduce.input.num.files", 1);` It seems that such a property doesn't exists?

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: It is v0.20.2, is it the problem?

Comment: 0.20.2 is not 0.20.203+, that's why it doesn't work. If you are using files which are compressed with gzip and an input format such as TextInputFormat, then `mapred.map.tasks` will most probably give you the number of input files.